# How to hide an UIImageView with Aspect Ratio autolayout constraint?

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a custom UITableViewCell where I have an image at the top with an Aspect Ratio constraint, and labels under my image with constraints relative to my image.

I wan't to be able to hide my image so all the labels under are moved to the top where my image is.

With a fixed height constraint, I could create an IBOutlet and set the constant to 0, and it would work, but with an Aspect Ratio constraint, I don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you describe what the ultimate design of the table view cell is supposed to look like (maybe a simple image of where things should go)? I feel like there may be a better way to situate your constraints, but without knowing what the end product should look like, I'm left to assume too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that I see here is - when you need to hide it, than you should:

1) Get width of you view
2) set aspect ratio constraint active = NO 3) create width constraint from value getted before 4) create height constraint with constant = 0 5) add this two constraints(if doing from code) 
6) Animate

As well you can create width and height constraints in builder with aspect ratio constraint and just manipulate with property `active`

Comment: I simply added a new height constaint with height = 0, setup IBOutlets for my AspectRatio and Height constraints, and in my code I play with the `active` property as suggested, works fine!